# VPN some websites do not load on a specific WiFi

Tags: networking, vpn, strongswan

I have a RaspberryPi 2 with strongswan installed on it, using suite B crypto, IKev2 and fragmentation on. When I Connect to this VPN with my MacBook on a Hotspot which routes the traffic over the UK, then most webpages do not load.

Stackexchange and Google services do work. But most other things do not work.

I wonder why this happens since the WiFi network should not have an impact on wich sites load?

DNS seems to work correctly over VPN and on my phone I have the same behavior.

Comment: MTU problems? (Check with `tracepath`.)

Comment: "should not have an impact on wich sites load?" - Even though you are using a VPN, depending on the VPN's configuration, you could still be using the DSN of the access point itself.

Comment: Now it works again. Probably it was a MTU problem. I will check it the next time when it does not work.